# How to solve page not found error in heroku after deployment

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to upload an express/node.js app to heroku. The app is deployed succesfully but when I try to access the url I get **error: Not Found**.

When I run **heroku logs --tail** I get:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/client/build/index.html'
```

so I think I'm doing something wrong with the directories and the statics folder

this is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const profile = require("./routes/api/profile");
const matches = require("./routes/api/matches");

const app = express();

//body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

//db config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

//cors
app.use(cors());

//connect to mongoose
mongoose
 .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
 .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/images")));

//Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

//Use route
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/profile", profile);
app.use("/api/matches", matches);

//Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.enable("trust proxy");

  //Set static folder
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../client/build/index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port ${port}`));
```

I also include an image of the folders "positions"[image: folders]

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by defining build and install command in my package.json. Heroku would look for a build command for production in there.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be like this

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
```

Edit: Actually your app is expecting to find a file at `/../client/build/index.html` but that file does not exist (which is what ENOENT error means). So you either need to create the expected directory structure or else configure your application such that it looks in the correct directory for index.html. That whats i understand now, i hope this would help you.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but the problem is still there. I upload the app and get the **not found** page

Answer (score 0):

I also got similar error. For me the problem is I have wrong script for build in package.json file, So build is not creating at all.

Verify you have "heroku-postbuild" script as below in package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client" 
},
```